# Trying to delete a single row in a table of 2 PK_FK in laravel

Tags: laravel

I am trying to delete one row, connected to a database  with Laravel and I have been looking over all the internet, and I am not able to find any solution.

So I need to make route/firstkey/route/secondkey on the file named api.php but I need that when I am doing the update method :

```php
public function delete($firstkey, $secondkey)
{
    // Find how can I delete the row.
}
```

Thank you a lot in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you declare the route. Since you want to delete, let's make it a DELETE route

```
Route::delete('route/{firstKey}/route/{secondKey}', [SomeController::class, 'delete']);
```

Inside your delete method, you need to make a query, but instead of ending with `get()`, you end it with `delete()`.
php

```
public function delete($firstKey, $secondKey) // param names are the same as the ones declared in the route.
{
    DB::query()
        ->from('table')
        ->where('column1', $firstKey)
        ->where('column2', $secondKey)
        ->delete();
    // DELETE FROM table WHERE column1 = $firstKey AND column2 = $secondKey
}
```

- [8.x Routing - Required Parameters](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/routing#required-parameters)
- [8.x Queries - Delete Statements](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#delete-statements)